When rtpjitterbuffer in gstreamer is configured in RTP_JITTER_BUFFER_MODE_BUFFER mode, there is no data output
When I connect appsrc, rtpjitterbuffer and appsink together, rtpjitterbuffer uses RTP_JITTER_BUFFER_MODE_BUFFER mode. I have output a large amount of data through appsrc, but the entire pipeline cannot get the output.
May I ask what is the reason?
How do I need to configure my jitterbuffer to output data smoothly?
